# How to Link to sql server DB Which itself is linked to another sql server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, sqlconnection

the issue:
We have a Db named for example 'DBUni' and 4 SQL servers In various cities

- Server1 is connected to Server 2
- Server2 is connected to Server 1,3
- Server3 is connected to Server 2,4
- Server4 is connected to server 3

**Problem: We have to have a SQL Connection from Server 4 to Server 1**

Right now 'DBUni' is on Server1 and it is Linked To Server2 through SQL Server Link Servers

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: you can directly add a linked server to server 1 from server 4 or any server .

Answer (score 1):

You could create a view on the linked server referring to the other linked servers, this could become an extensive list of views though.

The view would not be restricted to only the same server, since it can refer to a different linked server. This way you could make a hierarchy of views. I have no idea how this would affect performance though.